# Finding other solutions to $Ax=b$

Tags: vectors, matrix-equations, least-squares

I apologize as this is probably a very elementary question. I would like to know whether you can find other solutions to $Ax=b$, that aren't the least squares solution, a.k.a. a general solution.

Suppose I have found a unique solution to $Ax=b$ from either:

$ \begin{align} \bar{x} = (A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb \end{align}$ or $\begin{align} \tilde{x} = A^{+}b \end{align} $

Would I be able to use these solutions to find more general solutions? If I take a multiple of one solution, would it still be considered a solution?

Comment: Simply add to your solution the general solution of $Ax=0$.

Comment: I am assuming this will work since  $Ax = b + 0 = b$?

Comment: Worth noting that if you *require* the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse, your system has no solution, so there aren't "other solutions".

Comment: @KevinG: The set of solutions of a linear system $AX=b$ is an affine subspace, so given a solution, it is enough to add the directing vector subspace.

Comment: Do you mind elaborating on why there are no "other solutions"? From my understanding, $ \tilde{x} = A^+b $ is the unique solution with minimal length. What about this solution makes it so no other solutions can be derived from it?